# How to fetch the data from client server in ios using objective c.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

How can I fetch the data from a client server in iOS using ObjectiveC?

I have the IP, host, port addresses. I want to log in my application with that IP address along with having the username and password. Is this possible?

Comment: It's not completely clear what you're asking. Also, you need to include some example code and show where exactly you're stuck or what errors you're experiencing. "How do I do this?" without code for context aren't a good fit for StackOverflow. See more info at [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You should read about HTTP Post,GET methods.

Comment: Start with basic networking classes in iOS i.e NSURLConnection
Know about it from tutorials. Also go through NSURLSession with is more advanced. After that you can migrate to AFNetworking here is a tutorial about this library http://www.raywenderlich.com/59255/afnetworking-2-0-tutorial

Comment: Try this tutorial. It gives you a walk through about how to set up your back end web service for iOS and then how to connect to it-http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-your-own-web-service-for-an-ios-app-part-one/  http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/software-engineer/create-your-own-web-service-for-an-ios-app-part-two/